# libreoffice text missing in global menu

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, appmenu

I have installed the latest version of libreoffice a while ago and I just updated ubuntu 12.04. When I opened the libreoffice document, the text in the globalmenu is missing and you only see the highlight color selecteing the menu where the text would be.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:
A [bug was filled](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63840), and the PPA for 12.04 has been [rebuilt](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/17839/drop-down-menu-not-visible-in-lo-writer-calc/?answer=17905#post-id-17905).

Simply do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to deal with this bug for now is to remove the following packages:

sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk3

The menu will look like a Windows 95 app, but it shows.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem here, after doing an update just an hour ago. Tried deleting my user profile and also uninstalling, `apt-get autoclean` and reinstalling, but nothing seems to work. It still doesn't work when I install the Spanish language pack, which I hoped might restore the texts.

UPDATED: This seems to be the same as reported in [question 297743](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297743/libre-office-shows-blank-menu-and-then-crashes), which was closed as it corresponds to a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk

Comment: It would be helpful if you could you explain how removing a LibreOffice package would restore the text for LibreOffice?